# Mongo C++ Driver: mongo/client/dbclient.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mongodb

I am trying to install the MongoDB C++ driver on my machine. I have followed the directions [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-cpp-driver/), and everything seemed to install successfully. Still, I can't seem to include the headers. Here is a simple test program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "mongo/client/dbclient.h"

void run() {
  mongo::DBClientConnection c;
  c.connect("localhost");
}

int main() {
  try {
    run();
    std::cout << "connected ok" << std::endl;
  } catch(const mongo::DBException &e) {
    std::cout << "caught" << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here are the errors I get:

```
g++ app/tutorial.cpp -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system -o tutorial
app/tutorial.cpp:3:35: error: mongo/client/dbclient.h: No such file or directory
app/tutorial.cpp: In function ‘void run()’:
app/tutorial.cpp:6: error: ‘mongo’ has not been declared
app/tutorial.cpp:6: error: expected `;' before ‘c’
app/tutorial.cpp:7: error: ‘c’ was not declared in this scope
app/tutorial.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
app/tutorial.cpp:14: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘mongo’ with no type
app/tutorial.cpp:14: error: expected `)' before ‘::’ token
app/tutorial.cpp:14: error: expected `{' before ‘::’ token
app/tutorial.cpp:14: error: ‘::DBException’ has not been declared
app/tutorial.cpp:14: error: ‘e’ was not declared in this scope
app/tutorial.cpp:14: error: expected `;' before ‘)’ token
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to add the library in the directory from your compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `app/tutorial.cpp:3:35: error: mongo/client/dbclient.h: No such file or directory` indicates that g++ is having difficulty finding the installed headers.  In the tutorial that you linked to, the box below the suggested compilation command states

> You may need to use -I and -L to specify the locations of your mongo and boost headers and libraries.

I'll assume that the installation procedure placed your header files in `/usr/local/include` and libraries (e.g. `libmongoclient.a`) in `/usr/local/lib`.  Then, try adapting the compilation command to read

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system app/tutorial.cpp -o tutorial
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately, I don't think the lib installed correctly. After running `sudo scons`, both `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/local/install` have no mongo files. `scons` produced a build directory containing .o files and `libmongoclient.a` that I moved to the respective locations, but nothing happened.

Comment: Hmm...did you just run `sudo scons`, or were there other flags you passed in?  If I am reading the tutorial correctly, you may need to use `sudo scons --prefix /usr/local --full install`.  Without the `--full install` part, I'm not sure if the files will be installed correctly (perhaps they're just built but not installed, which would explain the presence of `.o` files).  Can you try to reinstall the driver with this command, and check `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` for the header and library files?

Comment: Also, just to double-check, you have installed [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/installation/) itself, correct?  The C++ driver does require that first.  (I would imagine there is a `mongo` binary in either `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`.)

Comment: Mongo is somewhere in my path. Also, when I try running with --full I get the following error: `SCons Error: no such option: --full`. This is what I ran exactly: `sudo scons --prefix /usr/local --full install`

Comment: I decided to give this tutorial a try for myself. I installed MongoDB just fine (using MacPorts, to be specific), and for me, it placed headers in `/opt/local/include/mongo`.  I downloaded the latest cxx-driver, and unzipped it to a local directory.  First, you are right that `scons --full install` failed.  The documentation is a little misleading.  So, I did a normal `scons` command (as you did before), and in the `build` directory, copied `libmongoclient.a` to `/opt/local/lib`.  I was then able to compile their `tutorial.cpp` using the command (continued in next comment)...

Comment: `g++ -I/opt/local/include -L/opt/local/lib -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_system-mt -lboost_filesystem-mt -lboost_program_options-mt tutorial.cpp -o tutorial`.  So, for you, (a) check if `/usr/local/include` has a `mongo` subdirectory (if not, find out where MongoDB installed its headers (e.g. I had a file `/opt/local/include/mongo/client/dbclient.h`) and (b) remember the directory that you copied `libmongoclient.a` to.  Then, replace my two paths above with your directories, and try to compile.  (You may have to remove `-mt` from some of the Boost libraries.)

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to do that. Everything is working now. I really appreciate it.