# Connecting Mongodb to C++ API #include problems

Tags: c++, api, mongodb, boost, include

I got the mongoshell and Json file all set up. I need help connecting Mongodb to C++

I typed this in the command prompt but it gave a a syntax error. (my file name is ConnectorMain.cpp)

-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -pthread -lmongoclient -lboost_thread-mt -lboost_filesystem -lboost_program_options -lboost_system app/ConnectorMain.cpp -o ConnectorMain

This person had the same problem: [Mongo C++ Driver: mongo/client/dbclient.h: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757683/mongo-c-driver-mongo-client-dbclient-h-no-such-file-or-directory)

The reason that there you need to type this in the cmd pmt is because it will allow you to access the weird #inclue files like: #include "mongo/client/dbclient.h"

I've visited http://api.mongodb.org/cplusplus/current/files.html

and this is the dbclient.h file

```
    #pragma once
    #ifdef MONGO_EXPOSE_MACROS
    #error dbclient.h is for C++ driver consumer use only
    #endif
    #define LIBMONGOCLIENT_CONSUMER
    #include "mongo/client/redef_macros.h"
    #include "mongo/pch.h"
    #include "mongo/client/connpool.h"
    #include "mongo/client/dbclient_rs.h"
    #include "mongo/client/dbclientcursor.h"
    #include "mongo/client/dbclientinterface.h"
    #include "mongo/client/gridfs.h"
    #include "mongo/client/init.h"
    #include "mongo/client/sasl_client_authenticate.h"
    #include "mongo/client/syncclusterconnection.h"
    #include "mongo/util/net/ssl_options.h"
    #include "mongo/client/undef_macros.h"
```

and it is crazy cause of all the headers so I am trying to figure out how to hook this all up and as the forum says it has to do with setting up a -I or -L because it relates to this forum http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-cpp-driver/#installing-the-driver-library-and-headers but that is in Linux.

Please help if you know how to do this. p.s. do I need to download boost and perl or something I saw that on another post. Anyways all the help is appreciated!

Comment: Where is your `dbclient.h` that you're showing actually located?

Comment: Just in my project header files.